# Getting user details from access token in Django rest framework -simple JWT

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am using React and Django rest framework for a project. I use Django rest framework simple JWT for authentication. Now, I want to display the username in the navbar after the user logs in. So, is there a way in simple JWT for returning user details from the access token generated after authentication, just like Djoser returns user credentials when supplied the access token?

Sorry if this question is silly but I was not able to find a solution to this anywhere.

Comment: https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html

Comment: Must have missed that. Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, @Aprimus that page just tells about how to customise the tokens. My question was if there is a pre-built function in simple JWT which helps in extracting claims from token or do I have to do it myself?

Answer (score 5):

if you want to obtain the information of the owner of the token you can consult it in REQUEST.

```
class ViewProtect(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        token_user_email = request.user.email
        token_user_username = request.user.username
        pass
```

Answer (score 4):

About the backend, basically I use this library

```
from restframework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
```

The function AccessToken() take as input the string access_token_str and return the object access_token_obj.

To get the user_id, you can use the instruction

```
user_id=access_token_obj['user_id'].
```

In the following example I have created the function

`get_user_from_access_token_in_django_rest_framework_simplejwt().`

This function  is just a wrapper around AccessToken()

Full code:

```
#Path current file
#/blabla/django/project004/core/view.py


from restframework_simplejwt.tokens import AccessToken
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#Example data.
#access_token_str = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VyX3BrIjoxLCJ0b2tlbl90eXBlIjoiYWNjZXNzIiwiY29sZF9zdHVmZiI6IuKYgyIsImV4cCI6MTIzNDU2LCJqdGkiOiJmZDJmOWQ1ZTFhN2M0MmU4OTQ5MzVlMzYyYmNhOGJjYSJ9.NHlztMGER7UADHZJlxNG0WSi22a2KaYSfd1S-AuT7lU'
def get_user_from_access_token_in_django_rest_framework_simplejwt(access_token_str):
    access_token_obj = AccessToken(access_token_str)
    user_id=access_token_obj['user_id']
    user=User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    print('user_id: ', user_id )
    print('user: ', user)
    print('user.id: ', user.id )
    content =  {'user_id': user_id, 'user':user, 'user.id':user.id}
    return Response(content)
```

Credits:

```
@davesque;
https://github.com/jazzband/djangorestframework-simplejwt/issues/140
```

Update.
The string access_token_str I write in the file is just an example. You should pass it as argument.

Comment: How does this do when `access_token_str` is expired?

Comment: The string access_token_str I write in the file is just an example. You should pass it as argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to customize the return data in this format:

```
{
    access: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2bl........Cj4",
    refresh: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ0b2t.........g",
    user_id: 15,
    username: "admin"
}
```

you need to customize and override the validate() method:

```
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView
    from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
    
    
    class CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
        @classmethod
        def get_token(cls, user):
            token = super().get_token(user)
    
            # Add custom claims
            token["custom_field"] = "Custom value"
    
            return token
    
        def validate(self, attrs):
            data = super().validate(attrs)
    
            user = self.user
            data["user_id"] = user.id
            data["username"] = user.username
            # ... add other user information as needed
    
            return data
    
    
    class CustomTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
        serializer_class = CustomTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

URLS:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenRefreshView

urlpatterns = [
    path("token/", views.CustomTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name="token_obtain_pair"),
    path("token/refresh/", TokenRefreshView.as_view(), name="token_refresh"),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I've done it.

On Django, I followed the steps described on this page in order to add the user's name inside the JWT token : https://django-rest-framework-simplejwt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customizing_token_claims.html

```
from rest_framework_simplejwt.serializers import TokenObtainPairSerializer
from rest_framework_simplejwt.views import TokenObtainPairView

class MyTokenObtainPairSerializer(TokenObtainPairSerializer):
    @classmethod
    def get_token(cls, user):
        token = super().get_token(user)
        # Add name to token
        token['name'] = user.get_full_name()
        # You can add other information into the token here
        return token

class MyTokenObtainPairView(TokenObtainPairView):
    serializer_class = MyTokenObtainPairSerializer
```

Then, I updated my `urls.py` to use the custom view:

```
path('token/', MyTokenObtainPairView.as_view(), name='token_obtain_pair'),
```

Finally, in my Vue.js application, I installed the [jwt-decode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jwt-decode) package and used it like this:

```
const token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
console.log(decoded)
// decoded.name contains the user's full name
```

Note that I store the access token in the local storage beforehand.